# Notify all objects of a class of property change

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have following class and there can be many objects instantiated from this class. I want to have this Visibility property shared among all objects. When visibility is changed for one object, all other objects should have the same value. I have view(XAML) per viewmodel which has this Visibility property bound to one element's visibility.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private Visibility visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    public Visibility Visibility
    {
        get { return this.visibility; }
        set { this.CheckAccessInvoke(() => this.SetAndRaisePropertyChanged(ref this.visibility, alue)); }
    }
}
```

What could be a good solution for this?

Comment: I would ask another question - why do you need it? Anyway, you could create a static collection and add newly created instance to it from factory method. After that every time someone changes `Visibility` you could iterate over items in that collection and modify them. But maybe you shouldn't. That will mess up with Garbage Collection (you could use `WeakReference` to fix that issue), and it seems like poor design in general. Are you sure you're not facing XY problem?

Comment: Your `ViewModel` shouldn't containing UI elements such as `Visibility`. This definitely looks like the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Consider refactoring your question, stating what it is *you want to do*, instead how you want it done.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to research the observer design pattern. In simplicity, a subject is created that has control over changing a value. Your subject would have control over the `visibility` property in your viewmodel. Observers would subscribe to this property and whenever your `visibility` property is changed, each observer would know about it

Comment: Thanks Zac. I am actually interested in knowing how the subject will be organized. Would it be a singleton class having visibility property? Or there is any better design pattern for that.

Comment: I might make the visible property static to the `ViewModel` class. 

The design pattern is called the "Observer pattern". This is in Java, but a very well-done video on the pattern: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wiQdrH2YpT4